# How can i wap the position of the label and the input tag with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using elementor in wordpress, i'cant modify the html directly, so i need to swap both tags with javascript (or css if that's possible) in the form.

The code i'm using in **CSS**:

```
    input:focus > .elementor-field-label {
    border: 1px solid black !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: translate(0px, -20px);
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

*Won't work because of the position of the tags.*

Then i tried this code in **javascript** to do the job:

```
    $('label').each(function() {
   $(this).insertAfter($(this).nextAll('input:first'));
});
```

*But don't work.*

So, how can i make this possible?

**FIY**:
The structure of this specific part of the form is this:

```
     <div class="elementor-field-type-text elementor-field-group elementor-column elementor-field-group-name elementor-col-100 elementor-field-required"> /*Using just the elementor-field-group*/
          <label for="form-field-name" class="elementor-field-label"> Texto </label>
          <input size="1" type="text" name="form_fields[name]" id="form-field-name" class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm  elementor-field-textual" required="required" aria-required="true">
     </div>
```

Comment: You could try to do it with flex: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order

Comment: If u want to use JS should be something like this ```$('label').each(function() {
   $(this).insertAfter($(this).next('input'));
});```

Comment: @ColdIV But that just changes the visual, doesn't it?

Comment: @EricMameluk Yes. The HTML structure would stay the same.

Comment: @Mischa didn't work :(

Comment: `$('label').each(function() {
 const label = $(this);
 label.after(label.next(':input'))
});`

Comment: @epascarello Didn't change too

Comment: Are you sure you are calling this correctly? Works fine for me. Is it going into the each loop? Is it finding elements?

Comment: @epascarello I don't know if it's correct, but in console show this: "Type Error: $ is not a function", maybe the problem is converting to elementor code.

Comment: So you are not using jQuery? I assumed you were since it was in your question.

Comment: No, i'm beginner in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With CSS you could do something like this:**

```
.elementor-field-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

.elementor-field-group input {
  order: -1;
}
```

This wouldn't change the HTML structure but visually they would swap position.

**With Javascript you can do it like this:**

```
document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-field-group label').forEach((e) => {
    e.parentNode.appendChild(e)
})
```

This script just takes the label and appends it to the parent again, so it will be the last child of the wrapper.

Or this, to add the `input` element before the `label`. This would be the better solution, if there are more than those two elements inside of the wrapper.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.elementor-field-group input').forEach((e) => {
  e.parentNode.insertBefore(e, e.previousElementSibling);
})
```

Comment: I want to change the HTML structure, the last JS code did the trick, thank you!
One more thing, can the code exclude the checkbox type from this change?

Comment: @EricMameluk sure, you could replace the `input` in the selector with `input:not([type="checkbox"])` to exclude checkboxes. Or just select text fields with `input[type="text"]`